# How do I retrieve all files in a directory on Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

On Flutter mobile I would write something like this

```
final filesDir = Directory(path);
final List<FileSystemEntity> entities =
        await filesDir.list(recursive: true).toList();
```

It doesn't work on the web since dart.io is not available. Is it possible to do something similar on the web?

Comment: Where would the files/directories come from?

Comment: So I would like to list all files located under build/web folder.

Comment: I don't think that's possible at least as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding files to app assets.